# Installing Cordova version 3.5.0

Tags: cordova

I am trying to download the Cordova 3.5.0 version.

On the page should be a link at the bottom of the page  - source zip.  Its not there on the page.

Where can I install it from ?

Answer (score 1):

The page you are probably referring to is the Cordova home page and more particularly the [download section](http://cordova.apache.org/#download). First sentence is :

> It is **recommended** that the cordova CLI be installed from npm rather
>   than downloading this .zip version.

You should really follow this recommendation (as I did) since the Cordova CLI will help you in numerous tasks that you really don't want to deal with by hand. See, Cordova is closer to a framework than a library meaning just downloading Cordova's sources won't get as far as you could go with the CLI (which help you build entire app skeleton ready to work from a single command).

If you still want to go with bare sources, here you go : https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/ (not sure about the 3.5.0 though, only the 3.6.1 seems available right now).

EDIT : sorry, the previous link redirect you to the lastest version, you have to go to the *archive* repo to find previous version : http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/

Comment: Thank you. I followed the second link and can see cordova 3.4.0-src.zip file.  I will try that.:)